# VK Validation required: please open redirect_uri in browser

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Мне выдаётся такая ошибка при вызове [groups.join](http://vk.com/dev/groups.join):

```
VK Validation required: please open redirect_uri in browser [какой-то id]
```

Через *curl* открываю этот *url*, но если после этого снова вызвать `groups.join`, *vk* вернёт опять эту же ошибку.

Если через браузер перейти по этому *url*, там будет написано:

> Пожалуйста, не копируйте данные из адресной строки для сторонних сайтов. Таким образом Вы можете потерять доступ к Вашему аккаунту.

http://vk.com/dev/need_validation - вот ссылка, но там не всё написано.

Как открыть этот *url* для валидации пользователя?

Comment: Возможно, при открытии ссылки необходимо ввести логин/пароль. Это делается по причине того, что в аккаунт произведен вход с подозрительного IP. Попробуйте открыть ссылку в одном из консольных браузеров, например [links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_(web_browser))

Comment: @soon не но а с браузера мне как сделать это для пользователей? тоесть с php я делаю это всё

Comment: Вот тут не подскажу. По логике, если запрос происходит с того же IP, с когорого производилась валидация, то `access_token`, переданный в url должен сработать. Я использовал валидацию только для инстансов ботов, поэтому не могу сказать, как это происходит для пользователей.

Comment: Предполагаю, что на него нужно перенаправить пользователя, чтобы он подтвердил это действие. Правда, после этого ВК должен его перенаправить к вам на сайт, для чего ему потребуется какой-то параметр (наверное?).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Если есть возможность установить NodeJS, можно использовать [этот скрипт](https://github.com/Yashko/vk-validation-node), дабы авторизовать аккаунт ВК на сервере.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял то вы собираетесь сделать регистрацию пользователей используя их данные из Вконтакте - возможно тогда вам подойдет такой способ - http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1659 - тут все сделанно через привязку к приложению через него можно получить определенный надор данных юзера - Аватар, Имя, uid и пр. Возможно вам подойдет это и не придется возиться с редирект урл

Вот как оно реализовано у меня http://onlinetracking.kz/comments.php

Comment: вот как оно реализовано у меня http://onlinetracking.kz/comments.php

Answer (score 0):

> Если через браузер перейти по этому url, там будет написано:
>
> > Пожалуйста, не копируйте данные из адресной строки для сторонних сайтов. Таким образом Вы можете потерять доступ к Вашему аккаунту.

Видимо вы в браузере залогинены под другим акком. Если открыть в приватном режиме, то вылезет формочка проверки телефонного номера, надо будет ввести недостающие цифры. CURLом решается без проблем: находите форму и ее action, находите начальные и конечные цифры, недостающие отправляете в переменной code. Только имейте в виду, что кол-во цифр может меняться.

Answer (score 0):

"Вконтакте" выдаёт такую ошибку, когда вы заходите из нового необычного места, и надо открывать ту ссылку именно из того места. Если ваше приложение работает с удаленного сервера, а не с вашего компьютера, надо зайти именно с сервера. В идеале - из вашего же браузера, прокинув порт.

```
$ ssh -D :8181 your-server
```

В настройках браузера установить прокси-сервер `127.0.0.1:8181`

Comment: спасибо, ответ стоит внимания. Вы авторизируетесь и получаете токен действительно то со своего компа, из своим же Ип, а не с ип"а сервера

Answer (score 0):

Понизте версию api до &v=3.0 и будет вам счастье

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?